# Tag area is bad aligned/formatted

Tags: bug, design

There is a problem near tag area, when creating a question. It is bad formatted\aligned. And a button a bit.
It's not a problem, but it frustrates a lot when you see it :-)

[image: Screenshot 1]
[image: Screenshot 2]
[image: Screenshot 3]

Comment: This problem appears in Chrome Version 38.0.2125.104 m (64-bit) and FF 33.0.

Comment: Oh, you're right! Am running Chrome Ver 38.0.2125.111 m (32-bit) on 64 bit machine. I never seem to see the "max 5 tags" when editing posts anymore. Good catch!